# python script for sync data from s3 to another s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I want to take backup of dynamodb and s3 buckets using lambda function with python code. Here dynamodb backup is like scheduling backup using cloud watch logs. S3 bucket backup also need to take like sync the data from one s3 to another s3 bucket. I want to take both backup using lambda function with python code and should scheduled in cloud watch logs. Can any one tell me to write python code for both dynamo db backup and s3 bucket? For example, my source bucket name is exambuclam1 and destination bucket name is exambuclam2. please any one help to write python code for this and tell me the steps to be execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boto3 (the newer boto version) this is quite simple

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'exambuclam1',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'exambuclam2', 'otherkey')
```

Comment: here whats the meaning of 'key': 'mykey' and 'otherkey'

Comment: some security keys are available in s3

Comment: just check using this link https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy